# USB 3.0 MicroB cable possibly causing failures

Tags: cable, usb-3

I have a Seagate 1TB Backup Plus drive that came with a 5in USB MicroB cable and have had it for less than a month. I purchased a longer cable, 6ft, and then tried to encrypt the drive with TrueCrypt. It failed a few minutes in saying the drive was possibly damaged. So I just figured it was a glitch. I reformatted the drive and started a backup using Cobian, which I had used when I first got the drive using the cable it came with successfully. It too went for a few minutes and then I started getting an error saying the drive was no longer connected. I unplugged it and swapped the cable for the one it came with, ran the backup again and it ran fine. Are there issues with using USB MicroB cords over a certain length? TIA!

Comment: Does the device respond similarly on other USB ports? Have you the most updated USB drivers?

Comment: SATA drives are supposed to be under 1 meter (about 3 feet). I wouldn't use a cable longer than 3 feet for a drive.

Comment: @BenPlont - The cable isn't a SATA cable its USB 3.0.  Your comment makes no sense.  Does not meant I don't believe the cable isn't at fault.

Comment: @Ramhound in mathematics it's called the Transitive Property. I know for sure that a SATA cable isn't supposed to be longer than 3 feet. So, for me personally, I think it's a good idea to keep all drive cables under 3 feet. Wether they be SATA, PATA USB or other.

Comment: @BenPlont - I have tons of USB 3.0 cables over 3 ft and present me personally without a problem.  You cannot compare SATA/PATA to USB for a number of reasons. one could be considered to be anexternal data bus, the other 2 are internal data buses..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would blame the cable. There are two things that can go wrong with a long cable.

1. The signal integrity is degraded when using a long cable. This can lead to random glitches.
2. If the drive is bus-powered (gets power over USB rather than from a separate power supply) the cable acts as an electrical resistor which may cause the device to fail to operate when using more power.

The USB standard doesn't specify a maximum length, but instead defines compliance in terms of electrical characteristics. This means that a 1.8 m (or as you yanks prefer to call it, 6 ft) cable could in theory be compliant. But the problem is that many of the cables sold are simply not compliant. Certainly for a 1.8 m cable I would think this is the problem.

What you should do is try to reproduce the same problem with the shorter cable. If you can, then the problem is not necessarily caused by the longer cable. If the drive is bus-powered, and you really need to place the drive almost 2 m away from the computer, you may want to invest in an externally powered USB hub, and use the shorter cable between the hub and the drive, to bring the power source closer to the drive.

Comment: A DC/AC powered USB Hub might help even with the longer USB cable. I would agree the problem seems to be caused by the USB cable itself. Its either of extremely low quality or there is something else going on. I personally have extremely long USB 3.0 cables that function without a problem but they were not cheap and I purchase more only after I verified every device was working with it.  To my credit I use several USB hubs and all are DC powered.

Comment: I have used the shorter cable that came with the drive successfully, so I'm thinking nitro2k01 may be correct, I'll test though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem, but this comment is for those who stumble across this Q&A. 
We've had the same problem a number of times, and the cable is not the problem, it is the USB 3.x Micro B receptacle / socket on the device. If you get a new case for the HD with a USB 3.x A receptacle these problems disappear. Unfortunately the 3.x micro B receptacle is small and fragile, and the 3.x Micro B cable large and stiff, it just breaks the solder and bam, no data transfer.